# Dynamic config file for shell commands in CakePHP 3.6

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have to work with multiple applications with the same code.
I have a project structure like below:

```
- same coding for all applications.
- different domains for different application.
- separate database for each application.
- different app.php and .env file for each application.(Ex. app1.php and .env1 | app2.php and .env2)
```

Now I need to work like I want to load different app.php and .env file application-wise.

How to load config files dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your `bootstrap.php` file. you can conditionally load your configuration file (`app_domain1.php` or `app_domain2.php`).

```
// config/bootstrap.pnp
try {
  Configure::config('default', new PhpConfig());
  Configure::load('env', 'default');
if (requestd_domain == domain1) {
    Configure::load('app_domain1', 'default', false);
}elseif(requestd_domain == domain2){
    Configure::load('app_domain2', 'default', false);
}else{
    Configure::load('app', 'default', false);  
}

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  exit($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
```

You can get requested domain with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`
Hope your problem will be solve
For more details check [Loading Additional Configuration Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#loading-additional-configuration-files)

Comment: Okay, Looks helpful, One another query is that, How do I differentiate the code for custom commands and How do I execute commands for individual domains. One another problem is that I think I need to run ACL rights grant command for individual domains. Is there any solutions for that all ?